# error TS2322: Type 'FC<{}>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Tags: typescript, types, typeerror, fc

Does anyone know what this is?

Test suite failed to run

error TS2322: Type 'FC<{}>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.

Did you mean to call this expression?

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

type Props = {
  makeLogin: React.FC
}

const Router: React.FC<Props> = ({ makeLogin }: Props) => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='login' element={makeLogin} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default Router
```

....................

Answer (score 1):

The type `React.FC` is a function, that returns a ReactElement. That's why TS is telling you, "Did you mean to call this expression?".

However, notice that when I prompt autocomplete, I can see the type of `element` in the tooltip:

[image: autocomplete demo]

The type is `React.ReactNode`, which we can then use:

```
type Props = {
    makeLogin: React.ReactNode;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AoUSWOAbzgCEcB3AZySgQgFcYOAaRDz6tBXXkjgBfONlwEi6GAFocEqMoAmuMuXIwAnmEkAFHGFZwAvHXJx7cECgDWSADIQA5sAB2ALkRiGAA6ZCUAOQhNJAopCnI0CB9WeHE+KACwjGCAMQBhAB4zCAsAPms4AAp6J1cPbx9pAOKLAEprcto7ByIYbihGyu6HBwKmCDYONI5S4ZH5gunWWfnVhem4MBQYAAsrfAAbL198OCQDpBAkHxgrWlr3Y58ZAHoVtZGCl6X31a-xyacYQzOatWLxJAAD2o8GimBQ3AOqWBUAoQA)

Comment: I tried, but the error changed to props and broke my tests

Answer (score 0):

change the Props type to:

```js
type Props = {
  makeLogin: ReactNode;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

please note that MakeLogin React.FC is function component and you just need use  to change it to ReactNode